# How do I copy a worksheet from one workbook into another new workbook with just that worksheet in (with pastevalues)?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that takes a worksheet from a workbook, and then saves that worksheet as a single workbook but with all cells as values rather than formulas.

The bit I am struggling with is the paste values section. 
This is what I have currently:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tickets (1-48)").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    For ColNr = 8 To 120
        If Cells(RowNr, ColNr - 1) = "0" Then
            TempValue = Cells(RowNr, ColNr - 1)
            If TempValue = "0" Then
                For i = 0 To 9
                    Cells(RowNr, ColNr - 1).Select
                    Cells(RowNr, ColNr - 1).EntireColumn.Delete
                Next i
            ColNr = ColNr - 1
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next ColNr

    .SaveAs strpath & "\" & "Retail " & strFilename & "(1-48)" & ".xls"
    .Close 0
End With
```

Ignore the section in the middle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is doing but you can adapt it to this. Here is the general code that a recorded macro will show you.

```
'Selects everything on the current sheet and copies it
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy

'Add a new workbook.
'Adding a new workbook makes it the active workbook so you can paste to it.
Workbooks.Add

'Paste the date using  Paste:=xlPasteValues
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("C8").Select
```

Comment: So simple. Thank you!